# How to resolve the logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

I have this exercise:

[image: Logaritm exercise]

My result is : $16/3$, but it does not appear in the answers, what is wrong?

Or is it another representation of the same logarithm?

Comment: You're right...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let apply the usual rules for logarithm

$$\log_a b=\frac{1}{\log_b a} \quad \quad \log_a b^c=c\cdot \log_a b$$

thus

$$\log_{27}3+\log_2 32=\frac{1}{\log_3 3^3}+\log_2 2^5=\frac13+5=\frac{16}3$$

Comment: So the guide is wrong ?

Comment: @EduardoCampos It seems so! By inspection I can't recognize any other answer s correct!

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right: $$\log_{27}3+\log_232=\frac{1}{3}+5.$$

Comment: So the guide is wrong ?

Comment: I think the answer in the book is wrong.